# Trying to put an image as a bg CSS SASS

Tags: css, sass

I've been learning some SASS from Traversy Media's course, and after a few months off coding have been getting stuck with this: I'm trying to put the showcase.png as my .landing's background through a url, but I can't seem to get the right path.

[image: File directory]

The image path I am using in my CSS file is `img/showcase.jpg`.

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the directory structure:

```
/
├── css/
│   └── style.css
└── dist/
    ├── img
    │   └── showcase.jpg
    └── css
        └── style.scss
```

The image path has to be **relative to the built CSS file**, not to the uncompiled SCSS file: so it should be `../dist/img/showcase.jpg`.

Comment: Hello Terry, thanks for your feedback. For some reason I didn't change the directory structure but it works with the path you suggested... I don't really know why... by the way, I'm a bit new to stack overflow and I don't know why but I've got an alert telling me not to use screenshots, how should I change this?

Comment: I think when you have code in your screenshot, it's best typing it out. E.g. you can share your CSS code for the image path as formatted code, and then attach a screenshot (or even better, use ASCII art like I did) describing your folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try url('../img/showcase.jpg')